# Double integral with polar coordinates - radius

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

it is me again.

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9}\right)^2 = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{9}$$

Now, obviously I introduce polar coordinates:

$$x= 2r\cos\phi$$

$$y=3r\sin\phi$$

The equation then translates to $$r = \sqrt{\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi}$$

Now, here is where I encounter a problem.

How do I know if the boundaries for $r$ are:

1. $ r \in \left[0, \sqrt{\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi}\right]$

or

2. $ r \in \left[\sqrt{\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi}, 1\right]$

I thought that maybe the boundaries are as in $(2)$ because the square root can be $1,$ but also lower than 1 depending on the value of the angle.

Also, please tell me if my boundaries for $\phi$ are correct. Here's my reasoning:

Since the left side of the equation is squared, it is always $\ge 0$. That means that the right side also has to be $\ge0$, so $\cos^2{\phi} \ge \sin^2{\phi}$, which is $\phi \in [-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$

Comment: The $\phi$ boundaries should be correct, and it appears that the $r$ boundaries should be as in your point $1.$

Comment: There are two loops, one for $\phi \in [-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ and one for $\phi \in [\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}]$

Comment: As for bounds of $r$, please note it is a polar curve centered at the origin, so any ray you take from origin to the curve is $0$ to $\sqrt{\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi}$. $r = 0$ at $\phi = -\pi/4$, $r = 1$ at $\phi = 0$ and again $r = 0$ at $\phi = \pi/4$. Similarly for the other loop.

Comment: @MathLover so does that mean I can calculate the integral for $ \phi \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and multiply it by $2$ to get the final result?

Comment: You meant $[-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$? Then yes, you can do that and multiply the result by $2$.

Comment: @MathLover Sorry yeah. Thanks very much! You're a lifesaver :)

Comment: A trigonometric identity will also make this easier to see:  $$ r = \sqrt{\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi} \ \ = \ \  \sqrt{\cos \ 2\phi  } \ \ . $$  So the radius for the curve is real only where $ \  \cos \ 2\phi \ \ge \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \ -\frac{\pi}{4} \ \le \ \phi \ \le \frac{\pi}{4} \  $ and $ \ \frac{3\pi}{4} \ \le \ \phi \ \le \ \frac{5\pi}{4} \  \ . $  The original curve equation represents a re-scaled lemniscate (of Bernoulli).